# How to add scroll in this page?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-apps, lightning-experience, lightning-design-system

How to add scroll in my component.I am beginner in lightning experience.I don't understand  how to implement scrolling on page.it's working fine for less record but if i take more record then its not work.

[image]

Comment: put it inside a div and use css `overflow:auto`

Comment: thanks Tusar, but i use this already but it is not working. <aura:component controller="ContactController"implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes">i have also use this but not working.

Comment: Did you use Lightning Design System?

Comment: no m not using lightning design system.I am using lightning component.

Comment: can you post your component and css code ? so that we can have a look at it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use newly added Lightning component in the Winter '17, **ui:scrollerWrapper** that enables native scrolling in Lightning Components Salesforce1 app as well as in Lightning Desktop.

In your case wrap the component code inside `ui:scrollerWrapper`.

> A `ui:scrollerWrapper` creates a container that enables native
>   scrolling in Salesforce1. This component enables you to nest more than
>   one scroller inside the container. Use the class attribute to define
>   the height and width of the container.

Please find example **code** below:

**Component:-**

```
<aura:component implements="force:appHostable, flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes">
    <div class="mainWrap">
        <ui:scrollerWrapper class="sWrapTest">
            <ul class="testDiv">        
               <li>In the Winter ’17 release, many of your favorite features 
                   are easier to use than ever before. 
               </li>
               <li>Lightning Experience has a brand new                      
                   navigation bar and lots of critical sales,
                   service, and analytics capabilities. 
               </li>
               <li>You’ve got more options for managing customer and partner
                   communities, running your business from your phone, 
                   and keeping your data and your users secure. 
               </li>
               <li>Not to mention plentiful new
                   customization and app development features, 
                   including custom Lightning apps.
               </li>                      
               <li>Other features require direct action by an administrator 
                   before users can benefit from the new functionality.
               </li>
               <li>If a key feature is also available in Salesforce1, 
                   our mobile app, we mention that in the feature description. 
               </li>
               <li>ui:scrollerWrapper
                   Creates a container that enables native scrolling in 
                   Salesforce1.
               </li>

            </ul>
        </ui:scrollerWrapper>
    </div>
</aura:component>
```

**Style:-**

```
.THIS .sWrapTest {
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Lightning Design System with Lightning Component then it has a known issue with salesforce.

Please check below link for more details and click "This Issue Effects Me" button if it occurs because of this.

https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p30000000ePVNAA2